# libvncclientのリンクでundefined reference error(wait3)

Tags: android

自身でビルドしたlibvncclient.a(libvncserverのビルドで作成される)を利用してndk-buildすると、

jni/src/../lib/libvncclient.a(listen.o):listen.c:function listenForIncomingConnections: error: undefined reference to 'wait3'

というエラーがでてビルドが止まってしまいます。
toolchainに含まれているlibc.aをAndroid.mkに含めてみたものの、
error:
 jni/src/../lib/libc.a(atexit.o): multiple definition of 'atexit'
というエラーが追加されただけでした。

どうすればwait3の参照を通せるのでしょうか。

参考にしたプロジェクト : https://github.com/ocrespo/VNCpp
libvncserver : https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver

情報の不足等あれば、教えていただきたいです。

環境
・libvncserverビルド環境
　VM上のdebian-jessie
　libvncserverのversion : 0.9.9
　android-ndk-r12b
　platform-14　
　arch : arm
　合わせてビルドしているライブラリ : libjpeg , libpng , zlib , libSDL

アプリビルド環境
　android studio 2.1.2
　Android.mk
　　APP_STL := gnustl_static
　　APP_MODULES :=  vncmain
　　APP_OPTM := release
　　APP_PLATFORM := android-14
　　APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

以上です。

Comment: Android NDKのlibcにwait3は存在しません。ずいぶん前にremoveされたようです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。wait3はremoveされているんですね。コメントいただいた通り、libc.aにwait3はありませんでした。sys/wait.hにwait3があったので使えるものと思っていました。wait4に変更して通すことにします。

Comment: この質問は解決したのでしょうか。解決したなら自己回答し、質問の横のチェックマークをクリックし承認して頂ければ嬉しいです。